Isekai manga story about a girl who reincarnated as a noble and create arms, train, get salt as a child
The only thing I remember was that the prince or son of the duke of the kingdom was tasked to go visit the territory of the female main character and she didn't want all of the technology to be spread or something like that.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember where?

FMC? Foreign Military Country?

@FuzzyBoots - 'FMC' almost certainly = female main character.

@Weirdo - What did you mean by 'train'? Did the MC train to learn some skill? Or did she build a physical train? And was this black & white or full colour?

Is this literal salt or child abuse/bullying?

This is Offense and Defense in Daites, aka Daites-ryou Koubouki, also identified here.

Ohmi Crown Prince Matisa has been ousted and ordered to go to the
province of Daites and wed its young lady, Miliana. Known for its
isolation, Daites serves as a place where he will never be able to
rally influence—the perfect place for the banished prince.
Contrary to expectations however, Daites is secretly a booming
province of wealth and innovation. The source behind this is Miliana
herself, who bears memories of her past life in modern-day Japan.
Using her photographic memory, she has introduced advanced technology,
new forms of transportation, infrastructure, and even weaponry.

The province is like Atlantis in that all of her inventions have been kept secret, and haven't spread outside of the now-prosperous but isolated region.

The prince was sent here to marry the MC because the queen didn't like him, and preferred his brother, and this was a way to get rid of him.
Her innovations do include a method of processing salt from a salt lake (instead of the ocean),

and a locomotive.

